# Exported SVG from Illustrator appears black

Tags: qgis, svg, illustrator

I have created 45 SVG Icons in Illustrator that I would like to use in QGIS, however all exported icons appear completely black. When using Save as > SVG I can mannually get it to work, though Export for Screens (to automate exports per artboard), however messes up the files.
Is there a way to alleviate this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Apperently, setting the Styling settings were the issue, Presentation Attributes did the trick:

[image: Export settings]